# I have hidden a "toolbar" panel on NetBeans and i dont know how to active it again

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't know what I did with one of my "toolbars" on NetBeans and now its hidden.

I want it to be displayed again.

This is the toolbar that I want to be displayed:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/HhRIhcI]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to re-activate it in `menu -> view -> Show Editor Toolbar.`
Check that option and the toolbar should be displayed properly again.

There are more ways to do it, but this is the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a faulty toolbar (or you're missing the main one) and cannot access the  `Window` -> `Reset Windows` function go to:

```
..\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config
```

and delete the `Windows2Local` folder (this one is for 8.2 version, but should be similar). Then restart the IDE.